# get cookie after set cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, web

I've set my cookie using set-cookie as follows on the server's cgi scripts

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n";
sys.stdout.write(cookie.output())
print "\n\n";
```

but when I reload the page I can't get the cookie as it doesn't appear
on

```
document.cookie
```

How do I get the cookies? and was Set-cookie : name=value
supposed to appear on document.cookie after I refresh the page?

Overall I want the client side to recognize the cookie if exists and act accordingly

Thanks

Comment: How did you set cookie, post your relevant code here.

Answer (score 1):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) is explaining it beautifully. You can have a look at the function getCookie and setCookie provided in the website. You can use that as a base. Its pure javascript

Comment: They use document.cookie there as the cookie string..and I dont have my cookie there...

Comment: could it be that my set-Cookie header is wrong? (You can see it)..I checked document.cookie on other pages and other pages did have more cookies

Answer (score -1):

Cookies are set out by the server. The client (browser) just sends them back. You cannot use Javascript to set cookies.

**EDIT**

You need fewer quotes and the `\r` is not required. Probably need `;` instead of `,`. i.e.

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n";
print "Set-Cookie: name=value\n\n";
```

Also use HTTP live header add-on for Firefox to check the HTTP communication.

Comment: By the way my cookie is as follows: name=12345; expires=Sun, 02-Dec-2012 14:26:00 PST

Comment: @ Ed notice that I now use cookie class in python, however now it prints the cookie as the body rather than as the header :-(

Comment: @user1432779 - You can have just `name=value` - See RFC2109 - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109